# Order by date AND id, sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some tables with date and id as two of the columns:

```
ID |   DATE   | ITEMS
1  |  7/1/13  | More Apples
2  |  6/29/13 | Carrots
1  |  6/20/13 | Apples
2  |  6/10/13 | Broccoli
```

I would like to order them by DATE and then group them by ID's so that all the 1's are together ordered by dates:

```
ID |   DATE   | ITEMS
1  |  7/1/13  | More Apples
1  |  6/20/13 | Apples
2  |  6/29/13 | Carrots
2  |  6/10/13 | Broccoli
```

How would I accomplish this?
I'm thinking my solution might be a sub-select but I haven't gotten anywhere closest to what I want to achieve.  Note that the above tables are very simplified.  I'm actually trying to accomplish this with many tables joined and many different fields being displayed. Thanks.

Comment: `ORDER BY ID asc, DATE desc`?

Comment: No, I don't necessarily want ID in descending or ascending order, I want all of my rows to be GROUPED by the ID. i.e all 1's together and all 2's together, and those groups of 1's would be ordered by date descending.

Comment: then what you want isn't really possible. ordering by ID will "group" the ids together, but if you want some OTHER ordering of them, you either produce a hideiously ugly `order by` clause to enforce that, or do the sorting in the client after you've pulled in the data.

Comment: Yeah I completely misrepresented that question.  The dates are in a different table, so my issue was to just use a sub-select with a correlated condition using the ID to match it. Then order by that subquery.  I oversimplified the question too much, but I figured it out now, thanks Marc B.